# How to get markers with no fill, from matplotlib 3.3.1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` has a `facecolors=None` argument that will give data point markers the appearance of being hollow on the inside. How can I get the same look for `pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter()`?

Answer (score 6):

It's option `c` (note that it's `'None'` not `None`, even for `facecolors` in `plt`):

```
df.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y', c='None', edgecolors='C1')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- It's difficult to find in the `matplotlib` documentation, but it seems `fc` and `ec` are aliases for `facecolor` and `edgecolor`, respectively.

  - See [`matplotlib.patches.Patch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html)
- The `pandas` plot engine is `matplotlib`.
- The parameter is `fc`. To use `fc`, you should also use `ec`.

  - Specifying `fc='none'`, without specifying `ec`, will result in blank markers.
- `'None'` and `'none'` both work, but not `None`.

```py
import seaborn as sns  # for data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins", cache=False)

# set x and y
x, y = penguins["bill_length_mm"], penguins["bill_depth_mm"]

# plot
plt.scatter(x, y, fc='none', ec='g')
```

[image]

- Using [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

```py
# penguins is a pandas dataframe
penguins[['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm']].plot.scatter('bill_depth_mm', 'bill_length_mm', ec='g', fc='none')
```

[image]